# Server Web Farm IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I am trying to set up a web farm where IIS configuration settings are replicated between the 2 servers.  I do not want to use a shared configuration as this presents another point of failure.  I have both machines (WWW1 and WWW2) set up to use a configuration file on D:\IISConfig\ on each respective machine.  With this done I  manually copy the configruation files from WWW1 to WWW2 and WWW2 works just fine.  I then took it one step further and added file replication to automatically push any changes on WWW1 to WWW2.  Then I added an App Pool to WWW1.  At this point I can also browse my website with no issues on WWW1.  When I went to IIS7 on WWW2 , I could see the new app pool . . .- GREAT.  I tried to browse the website on WWW2 and I get an error that shuts down the DefaultAppPool:

The Module DLL c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\authsspi.dll failed to load.  The data in this error . . .

Any ideas why this might be occuing and how to get arround it?

Thanks

Comment: ehh... I answered this for you the other day? - I cannot find it now, but I am, sure you asked the same thing.

Comment: I was unaware at the time I had this in Stack Overflo and should be here.  I move it to this site.

Comment: I have exact same problem but restarting services didn't change anything.

This problem started to occur when i used shared configuration functionality first time (not a production server. i'm learning here).

Any ideas? At first both source and destination servers were 2008R2 enterprise servers, now i found out that same thing occurs also in Win7 after i installed IIS to it and loaded configuration files.

App. pools stops after trying to go to a page. Same eventlog ID errors.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  On werver WWW2 I needed to restart the services to get it to recognize the changes in the configuration files.  When I stop and start the services, it all works as expected . . . so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. In my case, the solution was simple: 
On my "WWW2" server, I didn't have the correct authentication services installed as part of the Web Server (IIS) Role. By adding them (via Add Role Services), I was able to get past this error.